# how to avoid the seamless loop texture for a rope?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

hello guys I'm new in blender, I wanted to make a old ship and when i started to make ropes then I faced this issue, anyone can help with that.[image: ex]

Comment: Hello, is your image seamless? It should not happen if it is. But you could also use a procedural texture with a Wave Texture node...

Comment: Please pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file